# Retrieving Image from folder using codeigniter

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter

I want to retrieve image from folder and rest of data from database using CodeIgniter.

Right now I am able to retrieve data only from database.

Can anyone explain how to get an image from any folder and display it in a web page.

Comment: show us the database code

Comment: don't you save the image name in your database.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this procedure:

**Model**

```
function getDataByID ($user_id)
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT name, image FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = $user_id");
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $d = $q->row_array();
        if ($d['image'] != '') {
            $temp = $d['image'];
            $d['image'] = "http://domain.com/myimages/".$temp;
        } else {
            $d['image'] = '';
        }
        return $d;
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
function user_detail($user_id)
{
    $dt = $this->code_model->getDataByID($user_id);
    $display['user_data'] = $dt;
    $this->load->view('user_view',$display);
}
```

**View**

```
if(isset($user_data) && !empty($user_data)) {
    extract($user_data);
} ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <?php echo $name; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Image</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="<?=$image?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not answer too broad questions in future. These questions will get closed very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are constructing the page, but the easiest way to add an image is to set the data to a variable in **PHP** and adding it to the `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="{base_url}_assets/_images/folder/<?=$productData[0]->Image1?>" />
```